# Searching mongo for array of objects

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have the following data

```
{ "value": "apples", "category": 0 }
{ "value": "bananas", "category": 1 }
{ "value": "apples", "category": 2 }
{ "value": "avocados", "category": 2 }
```

I want to search the database for an array of objects.

If I didn't care about category it would be

```
.find({'value': {$in:["apples,bananas"]}})
```

How can I add the category field? I want for example all the apples with category: 0 and bananas with category: 1.

I don't want to 'for' loop and find them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve specific combinations you could use the [$or operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
.find({
  $or: [
   {'value': 'apples', 'category': 0},
   {'value': 'bananas', 'category': 1}
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's `{$in:["apples","bananas"]}` - an array of strings.
To match several fields you can use $or condition, if I understand the question:

```
.find({$or: [
    {"value": "apples", "category": 0},
    {"value": "bananas", "category": 1}
]})
```